# Laravel Updating Relationship Column in WhereHas

Tags: php, laravel

I wanted to update a column in my model with a wherehas. However, I'm not sure how to do this. Here's my query below

```
$unused = Sale::whereHas('salesdetails',function($query) {
             $query->where('product_id', '<=', 24)->where('switch', 1);
        })->where(DB::raw("(DATE_FORMAT(transaction_date,'%Y-%m-%d'))"), '<', $now)->update(['switch' => 0]);
```

Sale Model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Sale extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'sales';

    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'member_id', 'id');
    }

    public function guest()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Guest', 'guest_id', 'id');
    }

    public function salesdetails()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Sales_details','sales_id', 'id');  
    }

    public function discount()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Discount','id', 'discount_id');  
    }
}
```

Salesdetails Model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Sales_details extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'sales_details';

    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function sale()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Sale', 'sales_id', 'id');
    }

    public function product()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Product', 'product_id');
    }


}
```

In the query above, I want to update all the switches to '0' from the salesdetails relationship. How can I do this one?

Comment: this is correct one, you can proceed

Comment: whenever I use this query, it shows an error `column not found`, and I assume it is the switch column I am updating

Comment: which column tell me

Comment: It shows  Unknown column 'switch' in 'field list'

Comment: please add table structure and relations.

Comment: updated the model above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are updating the SalesDetails and not the Sale, I would reverse the query so that the update is actually on the SalesDetails instead of the Sale:

```
Sales_details::whereHas('sale', function($query) use ($now){
    $query->where(DB::raw("(DATE_FORMAT(transaction_date,'%Y-%m-%d'))"), '<', $now)
})->where('product_id', '<=', 24)->where('switch', 1)->update(['switch' => 0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying is wrong, You should try like this

```
Sale::where(DB::raw("(DATE_FORMAT(transaction_date,'%Y-%m-%d'))"), '<', $now)->salesdetails()->where('product_id', '<=', 24)->where('switch', 1)->update(['switch' => 0]);
```

I assume `transaction_date` column is in the `Sale` Model.

Comment: Hi! Yes, the transaction_date column is in the Sale model. I've tried your code and I'm having this error : Method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::salesdetails does not exist.
Note that I have the salesdetails function in the Sale model

Comment: Update your questions with the code for your Models

Comment: Updated it above

Comment: try to avoid using underscore in your model name, instead use CamelCase convention and also make sure to name your file same as model name